# Facebook games questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In the definition phase we started discussing if [questions on facebook games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190/getting-the-1t-and-10t-achievements-in-mafia-wars) should be allowed.

I'd like to start that discussion again, my vote would be *no*

[Another example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283/psychological-components-of-petville)

Comment: Perhaps we should "not allow" questions on Playstation games? This doesn't make _any_ sense.

Comment: I'm just re-starting a discussion @hob, the original spirit of the site was for computer and console gaming, not flash nor facebook mini-games. Please post your opinion as an answer or upvote one you agree with.

Comment: Those "games" aren't games but a waste of time, friends' sanity and often money.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll reiterate what I said during the definition phase:

At first, I thought we absolutely should take a hard-line stance against them, just as SuperUser does against web apps.

After consideration, however, I've completely reversed my line of thought.

1. Is the web not just another platform for content (in this case, gaming) delivery?
2. Many, if not most (or possibly all?) of these games -- particularly the Zynga ones -- have non-web clients. Yes, you are still online for the game and playing in that social space, but you're not in a web browser. Thus, what's so different about, say, playing Farmville via a client app (such as the much-hyped iPhone one) vs., say, playing Grand Theft Auto online? Or playing World of Warcraft? Or City of Heroes/Villains? Or racing your buddies in NASCAR 09? Or ...

I think, mostly on account of #2, that they should be considered valid. How are we to know -- and should care -- that a *ville player is using a web browser or a client app?

(And for the record, I *hate* *ville games, and Zynga in general. But that doesn't make them invalid for the site.)

Comment: I hate to say it, but I have to agree with this. While I don't really like how prevalent the *ville/Zynga games have become, I think that as a gaming site, you can't really just ignore them and pretend they'll go away. I read a pretty interesting article about this a few months ago, link: http://www.mmorpg.com/showFeature.cfm/feature/4097/Scott-Jennings-Farmville-Killed-Gaming-VWorlds-And-Your-Dog.html I think he brings up some valid points. While it is not "traditional" gaming, it is something that millions of people are involved in and that we should be prepared to have answers for.

Comment: Just for the record, those of us who play Zynga games also hate them. Just like crack heads hate crack.

Comment: @Jon B, haha, yeah I know how you feel. My Mafia Wars character has over 500+ levels. :(

Answer (score 3):

If they are tagged `facebook` then you can easily ignore them.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to have a discussion about what should be allowed on the site

Comment: @Juan - I am suggesting they should be allowed because they are so easily ignored.

Comment: With that reasoning you should allow gaming questions on SO as long as they're tagged "gaming" (because it would be easily ignored)

Comment: @Juan - I don't think that follows. Gaming is OT for SO. Facebook games are games, and are easily identified as `facebook`. I don't want to see the site become too elitist about gaming platforms. What else would we ban? Flash games? Cell phone games? iPod/iPad games? Let's attract a large, broad gaming audience.

Comment: ok, you're right, it's not a good analogy; and you're right also that the site should try to attract audience instead of driving it away. You convinced me.